# unable to get name, and output is undefined

Tags: javascript, web, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to get the user name, but the output is undefined. I still new to javascript on firebase.

```
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {

        if (user) {

            document.getElementById('welcome').innerHTML = 'Welcome! '+ user.name;
            window.user = user;
            alert( user.email);
            // User is signed in.

        }
```

Comment: did `user.displayName` help?

Comment: @user2520818 nope, the value return is null. Still researching

Comment: and if you console.log the whole user object?

Answer (score 0):

you may want to use the `displayName` property instead of `name`. Have a look at the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User) to see which properties the user object provides.